# Hook django up with postgresql using psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to hook my website up to use postgresql. I installed postgresql and psycopg2. In settings.py, I placed the following, and then got the error shown afterwards. I should mention that I tested the site with mysql before attempting to migrate to postresql.

from Settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {

'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'pdbt', 
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '', 
}
}
```

error:

```
DatabaseError at /viewer/

relation "django_session" does not exist

LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...
```

Comment: did you run `./manage.py syncdb` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out - I had to run syncdb! Yikes. Also, I see that karthikr pointed out the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

And if anyone is using newer versions of `django`, they should run this command:

```
//for newer versions
python manage.py migrate 

//for old versions
python manage.py syncdb
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see the above error message, it means you haven't created the tables yet.  To create the tables, just do the following:

1. Switch to the directory that you have 'manage.py'
2. Then do 'python manage.py syncdb' and you'll see the following:
   [image]